# tabs change back to first tab after a few seconds in Chrome

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have a page with 5 tabs on it.  It's setup to open to the first tab when the page loads.  When I click on one of the other tabs after a few seconds it changes back to the first tab again.  It should stay on the tab that is clicked on until something else is clicked not go back to the first tab.

It works in `Firefox` but not in `Chrome` and `Safari`.

The url is https://vcs.org/donate-now/

The javascript code is this -

```
 function openCity(evt, cityName) {
     var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
     tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
     for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
         tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
     }
     tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
     for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
         tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
     }
     document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
     evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
 }

 // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it


 window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
 };
```

Please help!!! I appreciate it!!

Comment: what is calling `openCity()`?

Comment: I don't know javascript well so this is code I got from the w3c site, I just didn't change some of the names they used.  The html is this -

Comment: Whoops - <li><button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Donate')" id="defaultOpen"><a href=""></a><h1>Donate</h1> MAKE A DIFFERENCE NOW</button></li>.   That's used for the first tab

Answer (score 0):

So you're calling...

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
};
```

Which then triggers another onclick event...

```
<li>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Donate')" id="defaultOpen"><a href=""></a><h1>Donate</h1> MAKE A DIFFERENCE NOW</button>
</li>
```

I would recommend setting active on the default tab, and then removing as you select different tabs. Here is a quick and dirty example.

```js
var tabLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');

function openCity(evt) {
  var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (var i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    if (tabcontent[i].id === evt.target.name) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  for (let a of tabLinks) {
    a.className = 'tablinks'
  }

  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active';
}


for (let t of tabLinks) {
  t.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    openCity(event);
  });
}
```

```css
button.active {
  background-color: lightblue !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="tablinks active" name="defaultOpen"><a href=""></a><h1>Donate</h1> MAKE A DIFFERENCE NOW</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="tablinks" name="other"><a href=""></a>Other</button>
  </li>
  <ul>

    <div id="defaultOpen" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
      defaultOpen content
    </div>

    <div id="other" class="tabcontent" style="display:none;">
      other content
    </div>
```

Comment: After doing all this, I would definitely recommend using a library like bootstrap or jQuery to make this easier on you. Especially if you're just beginning with javascript.